# How to find all the IP addresses a application uses?

Tags: ip, firewall, applicationpoolidentity

Our company computers have very limited access to Internet, when a application needs connection to internet we usually allow the IP addresses that application needs to connect through firewall.

Now I am trying to connect this particular application to their cloud service and added three IPs which I know it uses to pass through firewall, but the application still having issues to connect to the cloud. With unrestricted internet it connects without any issues.

Is there any way of finding the list of IPs this particular application uses through Microsoft network monitor or any other monitoring application, If so could you please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Install Wireshark on the same computer where the application runs, then perform capture while the application is trying to connect, by analizing the capture with Wireshark you could be able to see all the connection attempts

Comment: Yes I tried that, I was just wondering if there are any way to target a particular application and see their traffic instead of seeing all the traffics on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

Used Microsoft network monitor, Works really well once you start the process on there and start the application the left hand panel will show up with traffics on the apps that are connecting to the internet.